# scaleControl miles on top

Tags: google-maps

Using Google Maps APIv3.

- How do I make the Miles scale appear on the top of the scaleControl, rather than KM?
- Also: When I set `google.maps.visualRefresh = true;` not only do the Miles disappear entirely, the scaleControl appears in the lower right corner, even though I set:
  `scaleControlOptions: {position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT}`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See [issue 5449](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5449), the behavior with visual refresh true is by design.